# Why does apt try to install npm depsite it being provided by nodejs?

Tags: 16.04, package-management

I am using nodesource repositories to install nodejs on Ubuntu Xenial and when required to install package npm, apt tries to install the actual npm package. This baffles me, because the installed nodejs package provides npm as a virtual package:

```
Package: nodejs
Version: 8.11.2-1nodesource1
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Chris Lea <chl@nodesource.com>
Installed-Size: 59949
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.4), libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0), python-minimal, ca-certificates
Conflicts: nodejs-dev, nodejs-legacy, npm
Replaces: nodejs-dev (<= 0.8.22), nodejs-legacy, npm (<= 1.2.14)
Provides: nodejs-dev, nodejs-legacy, npm
Homepage: https://nodejs.org
Priority: optional
Section: web
Filename: pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_8.11.2-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
Size: 12650798
SHA256: d0d334108873d23567df07e120c82796582296702c50c48546def2772badfa0b
SHA1: 301d07117fd6989ff9833b3d5a6218a097d5be18
MD5sum: 0c12a6e18edc15fd11ee9bb1cacbab70
Description: Node.js event-based server-side javascript engine
 Node.js is similar in design to and influenced by systems like
 Ruby's Event Machine or Python's Twisted.
 .
 It takes the event model a bit further - it presents the event
 loop as a language construct instead of as a library.
 .
 Node.js is bundled with several useful libraries to handle server tasks :
 System, Events, Standard I/O, Modules, Timers, Child Processes, POSIX,
 HTTP, Multipart Parsing, TCP, DNS, Assert, Path, URL, Query Strings.
```

My understanding is that upon `apt-get install npm`, the system should state that package npm is already installed, but it tries to install a npm package which conflicts with nodejs.  Furhtermore, listing installation candidates with `apt-cache policy` does not list the nodesource package as a candidate, which according to my understanding is wrong:

```
# apt-cache policy npm
npm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.5.2-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
     3.5.2-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
     1.3.10~dfsg-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe i386 Packages
```